# Can I apply check out rules to a single document in a document library and not the whole library?

Tags: 2010, excel, check-out

Is it possible to apply check in/out rules to a single document in a document library without applying the same rules across the document library via the Library "Version Settings" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is a library level setting.

SPFile.RequiresCheckout is a read only property that tells you is 'check out required' setting set for the document library.

Comment: through reflection glasses, the same implementation is for `SPFolder` btw.